# What to do if Google has banned my site?

Tags: seo, google

What should I do if I suspect that Google has Banned (refuses to list pages for) my Site?

Answer (score 3):

You need to get signed up for and look at the Google Webmaster Tools control panel for your domain. Errors about crawling the site and warnings about malware and things like that will be shown there.